# How can i separate two data types in user input?

Tags: java

I am creating a calculator in which a user will directly input the numbers and the operator...

Here is my code:

```
int answer = 0;
int num1, num2;
char operator;
System.out.print("Enter calculation: ");
num1 = kb.nextInt();
operator = kb.next().charAt(0);
num2 = kb.nextInt();
```

The code above will accept the user input when there are spaces like this:

```
1 + 1
```

so the program will give an answer which is `2`.

But if i input `1+1` it will give an error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
```

How can i do that it will separate integer to character? because i set the operator as character. So that it will accept one digit to several digit numbers. Like `500+84` or `1520/872`, `30*5`, `148-65`?

Answer (score 0):

Try using 3 scanner?

```
Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);

int operand1, operand2;
String operator;

operand1 = Integer.parseInt(scn.next());
operator = scn.next();
operand2 = Integer.parseInt(scn.next());
```

OP changes his question I left.
I was away just now after I posted this solution. Didn't have time to improve it. Now I give you a **better** and **simple** **solution**:

I supposed you do not expect user to input things like "12+45*67/20" right? Assuming there will be two operands.

1) Receive input as 1 whole string

2) Trim all the spaces from the input

3) Split string into tokens of integers

```
Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);   
String[] token = new String[12];        
System.out.print("Enter equation:");
String input = scn.nextLine().trim();
String operator = "";
double answer=0, operand1=0, operand2=0;

if (input.indexOf("+") != -1){
    token = input.split("\\+");
    operator = "+";
}
else if (input.indexOf("-") != -1){
    token = input.split("-");
    operator = "-";
}
else if (input.indexOf("*") != -1){
    token = input.split("\\*");
    operator = "*";
}
else if (input.indexOf("/") != -1){
    token = input.split("/");
    operator = "/";
}
else
    System.out.println("Invalid equation!");

if(token[0].matches("[0-9]+") && token[1].matches("[0-9+]"))
{
    operand1 = Double.parseDouble(token[0]);
    operand2 = Double.parseDouble(token[1]);
    switch (operator)
    {
        case "+": answer = operand1 + operand2;
                  break;
        case "-": answer = operand1 - operand2;
                  break;
        case "*": answer = operand1 * operand2;
                  break;
        case "/": answer = operand1 / operand2;
                  break;
    }
}
System.out.println(answer);
```

Just copy and paste the whole thing to test it, it will work.

Comment: You run into the same problem as OP, just another exception.

Comment: @RavenMaddison That's not true.

Comment: @RavenMaddison As Scanner's next() returns a java.lang.String, the compiler will accept it.

Comment: @RavenMaddison I added some codes. It will 100% work. I am using simple codes to make it work, so your school should accept it. Even if you take out the line with `.matches()` It will still work. That is just to check whether both operands are indeed numbers.

Answer (score 0):

It does not expect negative operands. It throws an exception if a number is too big. It does not explain what the "error in expression" is. So there's plenty of room for improvement.

```
Scanner scn = new Scanner( System.in );
Pattern pat = Pattern.compile( "\\s*(\\d+)\\s*([-+*/])\\s*(\\d+)\\s*" );

while( scn.hasNextLine() ){
    String line = scn.nextLine();
    Matcher mat = pat.matcher( line );
    if( mat.matches() ){
        int op1 = Integer.parseInt( mat.group(1) );
        char od = mat.group(2).charAt(0);
        int op2 = Integer.parseInt( mat.group(3) );
        System.out.println( op1 + " " + od + " " + op2 );
    } else {
        System.out.println( "error in expression" );
    }
}
```

This is a simpler version. Similar caveats apply here, too. Moreover, it throws an exception on invalid numbers and accepts almost anything as an operator.

```
Scanner scn = new Scanner( System.in );
scn.useDelimiter( "\\b|\\s+" );
while( scn.hasNextLine() ){
    int op1 = scn.nextInt();
    char od = scn.next().charAt(0);
    int op2 = scn.nextInt();
    System.out.println( op1 + " " + od + " " + op2 );
    scn.nextLine();
}
```

Comment: @Tom Thanks - missed that after pasting. :-\

Answer (score 0):

I don't have much experience with the `java.util.Scanner` class.  But, I suspect that it tokenizes on a well-defined **token separator**, such as spaces, tabs, a comma, pipe characters, etc.  So, this may be a poor choice in tokenizing your type of input.

To successfully tokenize your type of input, I suggest implementing a proper *lexical analyzer*.  This may be overkill here (like using a tank to hunt a rabbit), but to do it properly and formally with some guarantee of success, you would need to write a lexical analyzer.  The web is chock-full of examples of writing a lexical analyzer.  For your input, it may look something like this:

```
public class Scanners {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Lexer lexer = new Lexer("32221-8  +45     ");
        for(String token : lexer)
            System.out.println("token = "+token);
    }
    private static final class Lexer implements Iterable<String> {
        private int pos=0;
        private final String input;
        private final int inputLength;
        private String token;
        public Lexer(String input) {
            this.input = input;
            this.inputLength = input.length();
            advance();
        }
        private void advance() {
            if(pos>=inputLength) {
                token = null;
                return;
            }
            char c = input.charAt(pos++);
            if(Character.isDigit(c))
                token = advanceNumber(c);
            else if(Character.isJavaIdentifierStart(c))
                token = advanceVariable(c);
            else if(Character.isWhitespace(c)) {
                advanceWhitespace();
                advance();
            } else
                // here, assuming a one-character operator
                token = Character.toString(c);
        }

        private String advanceNumber(char c) {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder().append(c);
            while(pos<inputLength) {
                c = input.charAt(pos);
                if(Character.isDigit(c)) {
                    sb.append(c);
                    ++pos;
                } else
                    break;
            }
            return sb.toString();
        }

        private String advanceVariable(char c) {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder().append(c);
            while(pos<inputLength) {
                c = input.charAt(pos);
                if(Character.isJavaIdentifierPart(c)) {
                    sb.append(c);
                    ++pos;
                } else
                    break;
            }
            return sb.toString();
        }

        private void advanceWhitespace() {
            while(pos<inputLength && Character.isWhitespace(input.charAt(pos)))
                ++pos;
        }

        @Override
        public Iterator<String> iterator() {
            return new Iterator<String>() {
                @Override
                public boolean hasNext() {
                    return token != null;
                }

                @Override
                public String next() {
                    String retval = token;
                    advance();
                    return retval;
                }

                @Override
                public void remove() {
                    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
                }
            };
        }
    }
}

// output
// ------
// token = 32221
// token = -
// token = 8
// token = +
// token = 45
```

Answer (score -3):

You can do it like this:

```
    Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
    Integer operand1, operand2;
    char operator;

    System.out.println("Enter first operand: ");
    operand1 = scn.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter operator: ");
    operator = scn.next().charAt(0);
    System.out.println("Enter second operand: ");
    operand2 = scn.nextInt();
```

Comment: no... my teacher said it to be user friendly..... so i shouldnt use that....... thanks for posting...